# Django 1.7 - create initial migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

According to [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#s-adding-migrations-to-apps), if I want to create an initial migration for an app, I should do:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations my_app
```

However, if I do that in my project, I get:

> No changes detected in app 'my_app'

even though there are no migrations for my_app yet - the my_app/migrations/ folder only has an `__init__.py` file.

I do NOT have [managed = False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#s-managed) in my model.  The model classes in question don't even have a Meta class defined.  What else can prevent Django from detecting model changes?

**How does Django detect if/when there are changes?**

*Update:*
I should add that migrations for this particular app worked fine back when I was using South migrations.  It's only after upgrading to Django 1.7, and built-in migrations, that it can no longer figure out if/when there are model changes for that particular app (migrations for other apps work fine).

Comment: Are your models defined correctly? I.e., are they inheriting from `models.Model`?

Comment: Yes, they are inheriting from `models.Model`.  Migrations for these models worked fine back when I was using South instead of the Django 1.7 migrations.  I was actually in the process of upgrading to Django 1.7 when I encountered the above problem.  I followed the "Upgrading from South" instructions, and then noticed that one app was missing migrations.

Comment: Try changing your model and running `python manage.py makemigrations my_app` to see what the output is (then you can undo the model change and delete the migration, leaving your code and database unaffected).

Comment: @mcastle - I've tried that.  No additional changes are recognized in that app, as far as migrations go.

Comment: @Filly - I had tried that.  Unfortunately, it's the same results.  For now, I've just manually created the migration.  That'll get me by.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but having just hit this after creating a brand new app, it suddenly dawned on me that I hadn't added the new app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    my_app,
    ...
)
```

Doing that and then re-running `python manage.py makemigrations my_app` generated the initial migration.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for a "migrations" directory somewhere in your virtualenv home directory or on your path.

I ran a few times into some similar issue, when trying to migrate an app from South to Django 1.7 migrations. For some reason, Django wouldn't find the correct migrations folder, and so would create the migration into an unlikely location such as `<virtualenv>/bin/myapp/migrations` dir (when using `django-admin.py`). So everytime I'd run `makemigrations` Django would find this "stale" migration, and display the `No changes detected in app 'my_app'` message.

*Sorry if I'm vague on the specifics, I'll update next time I run into this issue.*